# TypeError: descriptor '__init__' requires a 'super' object but received a 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Using Python 3.X as the interpreter. I just had inherited the `Employee` class with two of the derived class as `Developer` and `Manager`.

The below code is throwing a Type Error:  `'__init__' requires a 'super' object but received a 'str'`.
I'm not getting why exactly it's happening, I don't find any problem with the program yet.

```
class Employee:
    raise_amount=1.05
    emp_count=0
    def __init__(self,first_name,last_name, amount):
        self.first_name=first_name
        self.last_name=last_name
        self.amount=amount
        self.email_id="{0}.{1}@{1}.com" .format(first_name,last_name)
        Employee.emp_count +=1

    def fullname(self):
        print ("%s %s"%(self.first_name,self.last_name))

    def print1(self):
        print (self.email)
        print ("Total no of Employee are :%d" %(Employee.emp_count))


    def raise_amount(self):
        self.amount *=self.raise_amount
        return self.amount


class Developer(Employee):
    raise_amount = 1.10
    def __init__(self,f,l,a,prog):
        super.__init__(f,l,a)
        self.programming=prog

class Manager(Employee):
    def __init__(self,f,l,a,emp=None):
        super.__init__(f,l,a)
        if emp is None:
            self.my_employee=[]
        else:
            self.my_employee=emp



    def add_employee(self,emp):
        if emp in self.my_employee:
            print("employee is already exist")
        else:
            self.my_employee.append(emp)

    def remove_employee(self,emp):
        if emp in self.my_employee:
            self.my_employee.remove(emp)

    def print_employee(self):
        for emp in self.my_employee:
            print (emp.fullnamme())



dev1=Developer("subhendu","panda",500000,"Python")
dev1.raise_amount()
dev2=Developer('Aditya','bishoyi',5688989,'java')
dev2.fullname()
dev1.fullname()
emp1=Employee("tonu","trip",30000)
emp1.raise_amount()
emp1.fullname()
mgr1=Manager("Biplab","choudhury",5000000)
mgr1.fullname()
mgr1.add_employee(dev1)
mgr1.add_employee(emp1)
mgr1.add_employee(dev2)
mgr1.print_employee()
mgr1.remove_employee(dev1)
mgr1.print_employee()
```

**Error trace:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:/Users/Subhendu/PycharmProjects/hello/inheritance.py", line 56, in 
<module> dev1=Developer("subhendu","panda",500000,"Python") 
File "C:/Users/Subhendu/PycharmProjects/hello/inheritance.py", line 27, in
init super.__init__(f,l,a) TypeError: descriptor 'init' requires a 'super'
object but received a 'str'
```

Comment: Post your error traceback, not just the message. You're asking us to work out where the problem is, when that info is already in the traceback.

Comment: You need to actually call super - i.e `super().__init__()`

Comment: That's done by mistake. I had removed the repeating ones. Still if you do have problem you can do the needful.  Thanks for your Support

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Subhendu/PycharmProjects/hello/inheritance.py", line 56, in <module>
    dev1=Developer("subhendu","panda",500000,"Python")
  File "C:/Users/Subhendu/PycharmProjects/hello/inheritance.py", line 27, in __init__
    super.__init__(f,l,a)
TypeError: descriptor '__init__' requires a 'super' object but received a 'str'

Comment: Always put the error trace in the question, not in a comment

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your `super` call giving the error in the `Developer` class should be:

```
super(Developer, self).__init__(f, l, a)
```

In the `Manager` class:

```
super(Manager, self).__init__(f, l, a)
```

You have other issues, for example, in `Employee` you have two attributes called `raise_amount`, one is a `float` and one is a method (function).  That's not allowed and the `float` takes precedence, so  `dev1.raise_amount()` fails.

In `print_employee()` you mis-spell `emp.fullname`

Comment: Thanks, It's executed fine.

Answer (score 54):

Change all of your `super.__init__(...)` calls to `super().__init__(...)`. The problem was the missing pair of parentheses `()`.

From the official Python 3.3 reference [here](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#super), *super* is actually a built-in function with the signature `super([type[, object-or-type]])`.

Answer (score 7):

```
def __init__(self,millage,cost,name,tyre,hp):
    super().__init__(millage,cost)
    self.name=name
    self.tyre=tyre
    self.hp=hp
```

super() you forget to put ()

Comment: Please try to give quality answers. This solution has already been provided by others two years ago ?